# Navigation Controller dealloc

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, memory-management

I am having a doubt regarding the behaviour of dealloc in ARC in Nav bar applications.I have a nav bar application in which 5 screens are there.I am pushing the view controllers in the navigation stack and has written the dealloc function in respective VC where i am releasing the strong reference variables.Dealloc's are called many times but the memory footprint is still going up.**IS the VC de-alloced only when he is popped from the navigation stack or it would be called after some time in the stack**.

I don't have the back button in the navigation bar for the user as it is not necessary.So should I manually remove the VCs from the navigation stack or they would be deallocated by ARC by its own?Any help would be appreciated as I am really stuck up with app crash issue.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` manages its view controllers' memory by itself.

If your memory footprint is increasing, that must be due to some other memory leak.